# jsPDF - Error - Failed to load PDF document in Chrome

Tags: jspdf

Trying to build a test pdf with jspdf 1.5.3 and it works fine with jsfiddle. But when I use the exact same script on my apache or iis servers, chrome cannot open the pdf. When I look at the pdf in a text viewer, it appears my version has some additional binary code.

This is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10);
doc.save('xyz.pdf');
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Working version on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/orz3jb4v/

Here is a screenshot of both versions side by side in text editor:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmXDc.png

(Invalid pdf on left)

Edit: After testing, this only happens with version 1.5.3. Reverting to 1.5.2 works perfectly fine. I can't find why this only happens on certain servers.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't understand why such a simple test wasn't working for me either. The really strange thing is, I have another project hosted on the same server that's using 1.5.3 and it works perfectly fine. I have no clue what the issue here could be. Did you happen to submit a bug report?

Comment: Tried jspdf 1.3.4 version. This resolved the issue for me.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43552373/9590487