# What causes JSPDF Locally saved file to give document [110] error with Acrobat

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, acrobat

I am generating a pdf from some HTML and on button click triggering my download function which creates a pdf. It opens fine in chrome but gives an error [110] when opened by Acrobat. Anyone knows what causes the error?

```js
function pdfd() {
    document.getElementById("bbasbb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("pdfaspdf").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("bannerg").style.display = "block";
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#asm")).then(canvas => {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.getElementById("pdfgi").src = imgData;
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a2');
        var source = "<br><Br>" + document.getElementById("pdfg").innerHTML;
        specialElementHandlers = {
            '#elementH': function(element, renderer) {
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 50,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 100,
            width: 522
        };

        pdf.fromHTML(source, margins.left, margins.top, {
                'width': margins.width,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

            function(dispose) {
                pdf.save("<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>");
                document.getElementById("bbasbb").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("pdfaspdf").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("bannerg").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("pdfgi").src = "";
            }, margins);
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSPDF Saved file locally gives document \[110\] error with Acrobat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939472/jspdf-saved-file-locally-gives-document-110-error-with-acrobat)

Comment: Already checked, could not understand what was causing the issue